# Fancybox with ASP .NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I am unsure how to get fancybox running in Visual Studio.

I've got the jquery going and if you click on the anchor to trigger the pop up it triggers fancybox which is all fine.

The issue is that I am wanting to have a dedicated .aspx page to populate the "fancybox" if that makes sense.

I am just unsure how to link or hook up the page I want to use to fancy box.

Here is my JQuery:

```
// Category Results Add Basket Pop Up

$("#list-category-results li .add-basket").fancybox({
    width: 620,
    height: 500,
    autoDimensions: false
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <ul id="list-category-results" class="clearfix">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/categorylist_child_dummy.jpg" alt="categorylist_child_dummy" />
            <span class="result-info">
                <span class="result-type">Moquito Net</span>
                <span class="result-price">$12</span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="add-basket">Add to gift basket</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to be able to reuse fancybox over and over again on different pages.  For this you probably want to use a User Control, not another .aspx web form.  user controls (among other things) allow you to use the same markup over and over again across your entire site.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>

<ul id="list-category-results" class="clearfix">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="<%= ImageURL %>" alt="<%= AltText %>" />
                <span class="result-info">
                    <span class="result-type"><%= Type %></span>
                    <span class="result-price"><%= Price %></span>
                </span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="add-basket">Add to gift basket</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Your Code behind

```
 public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        public string AltText { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             // You can put code relevant to the fancybox images here
        }
    }
```

And on each Web Form (.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Title="FancyBox Test Page .aspx" Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="MyPrefix" TagName="Thing" %>

<!-- jquery and fancybox JS goes here -->

<MyPrefix:FancyBox Type="type goes here" Price="90" ImageURL="SRC to image" runat="server" AltText="This is the First Fancybox Control" />


<MyPrefix:FancyBox Type="type2 goes here" Price="90" ImageURL="SRC to image2" AltText="This is a Second Fancybox Control, you can reuse this tag!" runat="server" />
```